# Need token from app key and secret to get post details in linkedin

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am building a website where user share status on his linkedin profile and it work well and I store the updated key comming in response.

I want to get like count on the status post on linked with stored updated id.

I used `likes($updateId)` function of Linkedin API but getting error in response.

Error:

```
     ["linkedin"]=>
  string(248) "

  403
  1441210265486
  5HFGUYUC2I
  0
  Access to network denied

"
  ["info"]=>
  array(23) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(99) "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-XXXXXXXXX/likes"
    ["content_type"]=>
    string(22) "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
    ["http_code"]=>
    int(403)
    ["header_size"]=>
    int(478)
    ["request_size"]=>
    int(497)
    ["filetime"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
    int(0)
    ["redirect_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["total_time"]=>
    float(0.850914)
    ["namelookup_time"]=>
    float(0.196039)
    ["connect_time"]=>
    float(0.197897)
    ["pretransfer_time"]=>
    float(0.301204)
    ["size_upload"]=>
    float(0)
    ["size_download"]=>
    float(248)
    ["speed_download"]=>
    float(291)
    ["speed_upload"]=>
    float(0)
    ["download_content_length"]=>
    float(248)
    ["upload_content_length"]=>
    float(0)
    ["starttransfer_time"]=>
    float(0.850901)
    ["redirect_time"]=>
    float(0)
    ["redirect_url"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["primary_ip"]=>
    string(13) "XXXX"
    ["certinfo"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["oauth"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["header"]=>
    string(325) "Authorization: XXXX"
    ["string"]=>
    string(353) "XXXXX"
  }
  ["success"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["error"]=>
  string(54) "HTTP response from LinkedIn end-point was not code 200"
}
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong in this an how to get linkedin post status like using Linkedin API.

Comment: Have you even bothered to look at the linkedin API manual?

Comment: I tried the step given in API doc but not get success with get post likes() function and post on feed done successfully.